# Java Jtable connect and get data from MsSql Server

Tags: java, sql-server, import, jtable

I am new at java swing because of that in my project i couldn't connect and get data from Microsoft sql server to Jtable.

But in this time I have just done it but I still interesting that if I don't use code, if I want to use that without code what should I do? In 'Netbeans', if you click table contents there is a way for import data to form. that is the point what I couldn't.

I tried to use this button(import data to form) and I showed my sqlserver.jar and I couldn't.

Answer (score 0):

I think is that what you want:
http://fahdshariff.blogspot.com.br/2010/02/display-any-resultset-in-jtable.html
But in java, you will not get without some code.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem and the code below helped so I could retrieve the desired data. Edit the code so it will get the information you want it to retrieve.

```
private class RemoveBookings implements ActionListener {

     String bookingID;

     @Override
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
         if (theMainViewDisplay.bookingData.getSelectedRow() != -1) {
             final DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) theMainViewDisplay.bookingData.getModel();

             // Get stored varible
             int index = theMainViewDisplay.bookingData.getSelectedRow();
             System.out.println(index);
             theMainViewDisplay.bookingID = model.getValueAt(index, 0).toString();
             theMainViewDisplay.pickUpLocation = model.getValueAt(index, 2).toString();
             theMainViewDisplay.dropOffLocation = model.getValueAt(index, 3).toString();
             System.out.println(theMainViewDisplay.bookingID);

             // Remove booking from database
             model.removeRow(theMainViewDisplay.bookingData.getSelectedRow());
             theBackendModel.thePowList.remove(bookingID);
         }
     }
 }
```